# What type of data files should be used with Protractor

Tags: json, typescript, protractor

Is there a recommended way to handle data from data file in protractor scripts?

If I want to keep all the test data (like login details, user input values) in separate data file then what type of file should I use and how should I import them to my protractor scripts?

Comment: Depends on who is filling the data, If a person is familiar with `json` then it is very useful or else you can use `excel` . One more pactice you can follow is the code should be for `json`only  and whatever may be the input `excel` or `json` finally it is getting converted into `json` only.

Comment: What is the best way to import data from json file in protractor tsc script. An example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If suppose you need to work with `json` then:

Suppose your `json` for username and password of a login page looks like:

Example of JSON:

```
[
 {
   "username": "kishan",
   "password": "patel"
 } 
]
```

Then you can simply import this to your code and access it as below.

```
  describe ('Login Page Data Driven' , function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;


beforeEach(function(){
 browser.get('your url');
 browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
 });

it('To verify Login, using Data Driven Technique from Json file', function()        

{
 var testData = require('D:/json path'); //this is the path where your json is stored   
   var user= element(by.id("username"));
   var password = element(by.id("password"));
   user.sendKeys(testData[0].username);
   password.sendKeys(testData[0].password);       
});
```

This Is just an Example. I hope you can Relate and apply.
Try at your end & Let me know for more concerns.

Comment: ` var testData = require('D:/json path');` You can define it globally

Comment: Thanks Kishan. Your code helped. It worked for me with a small correction. I had to call the variable as testData[0] instead of testData[1].

Comment: Yeah. Indexing starts from`0`.

Answer (score 0):

I typically create a separate data file, and `require` it as needed in my specs. I have a [working example on my github protractor-examples](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor-example) repo. Here's the jist:

```
// userData.js
var UserData = {
    testUser : {'username': 'test', 'password': 'test'},
};
module.exports = UserData;
```

then in my spec...

```
// nonAngularLoginSpec.js
it('should goto friend pages on successful login', function() {
    loginPage.loginAs(userData.testUser);

    expect(friendPage.at()).toBeTruthy();
});
```